# Fluxctl: command not found

Tags: flux, fluxcd

I try to install fluxctl for my Kubernetes cluster but I always get the following error:

[image]

And I get the same result with my superuser account (sudo).

I'm completely lost

Can someone help me with this?  I didn't find any answer on the Internet (Google).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the absolute path:
/snap/fluxctl/current/bin/fluxctl

Comment: Do this `PATH=$PATH:/snap/fluxctl/current/bin`.

Comment: @noemie is that the answer?

Comment: Rico :  yes! it works for me. Even if it's not very practical